# Python: parsing issue on empty values

Tags: python, parsing

I have a following function

```
def best(x):
    xx = min(x.split(","), key=lambda x: re.findall("\d+.\d+", x.split()[0]))
    source = xx.split()[1][1:-1]
    value = re.findall("\d+.\d+", xx.split()[0])[0]
    return value,source
```

that work perfectly for this

```
3.4-10.4 (BDB),0.1-15.2 (BDB),0.2-17 (BDB) # working great
```

but does not work for this

```
3.4-10.4 (BDB),,0.1-15.2 (BDB),0.2-17 (BDB) # not working
```

Can you, please, suggest, what is the problem?
The error is "list index is out of range"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are splitting on the comma, but with two commas side-by-side you'll have empty strings in the result:

```
>>> x = '3.4-10.4 (BDB),,0.1-15.2 (BDB),0.2-17 (BDB)'
>>> x.split(',')
['3.4-10.4 (BDB)', '', '0.1-15.2 (BDB)', '0.2-17 (BDB)']
```

This in turn leads to the empty lists when trying to split that empty string further:

```
>>> x.split(',')[1].split()
[]
```

and that leads to an index error on `[0]`.

Filter out the empty values; using `filter(None, ..)` would do that nicely:

```
xx = min(filter(None, x.split(",")), key=lambda x: re.findall("\d+.\d+", x.split()[0]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> min(filter(None, x.split(",")), key=lambda x: re.findall("\d+.\d+", x.split()[0]))
'0.1-15.2 (BDB)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The split function is creating an empty value "" in the resulted list.

'3.4-10.4 (BDB),0.1-15.2 (BDB),0.2-17 (BDB)'.split(',') returns ['3.4-10.4 (BDB)', '0.1-15.2 (BDB)', '0.2-17 (BDB)']

as "3.4-10.4 (BDB),,0.1-15.2 (BDB),0.2-17 (BDB)" returns ['3.4-10.4 (BDB)', '', '0.1-15.2 (BDB)', '0.2-17 (BDB)']

You're accessing an empty value at some point.